# SQS Messages are moving to DLQ without processing even once

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

**Messages are moving to DLQ without processing even once.**

1. Messages available : 1500
2. Messages processed : 1430
3. Moved to DLQ without processing even once : 70

I want to know the reasons why these 70 messages are moved to DLQ even atleast once processing

Checked online/stackoverflow but didn't find anything related to this.

I checked logs for these messages but didn’t find like I found for others.
I didn’t open AWS console and saw the messages which will increase max_receives which I didn’t do.

**I am using @sqsListener to process 20 messages at a time irrespective of how many messages we get.**

So, there no possibility of system hangout/something.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you think it's something related to throttling? A wild guess though.

Comment: @Pacifist_AWS I checked my reports and dashboards but nothing seems though

Comment: It sounds like the messages being written directly to the DLQ instead of the main queue - otherwise what you're describing is impossible

Comment: Did you ever find the cause for this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Too late but I faced same problem. In my case I found few messages in my DLQ where those `messageId` were not even pulled/processed by my lambda function (why?!?). Aclaration: it was minor percentage (20 over +10k messages) but sometimes it happened.

Searching why ocurred this, I found this [paragrahp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/working-with-messages.html#avoiding-inconsistent-message-processing) on AWS documentation:

> Because Amazon SQS is a distributed system, it is possible for a consumer to not receive a message even when Amazon SQS marks the message as delivered while returning successfully from a ReceiveMessage API method call.

There is a possibility that few message couldn't been processed by SQS service and then those message are sent to DLQ because are consider as "failed". Thats why AWS suggest us setting the number of maximum receives at least to 5, default value is 10, for a DLQ (in my case was setted to 1).

Upgrating my `maxReceiveCount` to 5 solved my issue.

Hope this answer helps someone :)